# Installing Pointcloud Library, Boost.Python, and Conda Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, conda, point-cloud-library

I have been trying for about a month now to install Pointcloud Library and Boost.Python with Conda Python all together for an application I am trying to port to Ubuntu 16.04 running in a Docker container. Everything builds and works fine in Windows, but each method I've tried in Ubuntu to install these libraries results in a failure in one way or another. I've searched, but nobody seems to be using all three of these dependencies.

The application I'm porting is a set of Python modules and a few C++ functions. The Python code requires a fair bit of dependencies which are handled by building a Conda environment running Python 3.6.

PCL and Boost.Python come into play because the library has C++ functions which use PCL which are then wrapped using Boost.Python to create a Python interface for the functions.

I can get any 2/3 to work, but not all three together. I can provide the specific issues I face when I try each installation method if anybody is curious, but what I'm really wondering is if anybody else has successfully gotten these libraries to all work together on Ubuntu 16.04?

I've seen people wrap PCL functions with Boost.Python, but the real kicker is that it all has to be done with Conda Python under the hood.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail of one of your attempts, specifically the error messages that are produced and how the project is configured/built? I'm afraid this is going to be too broad, but we can at least try to help

Comment: One example I can think of is after I get all the dependencies installed I'll try and build my code using CMake. However, I get a bunch of warnings that the libraries I am including from /usr/lib also exist in the conda environment which later causes conflicts. Another issue is if I try and get PCL and Boost from apt, I end up not being able to set version of Python Boost.Python should link against. I need it to link to the conda Python installed in the environment, but instead it will default to the system version.

Comment: I should also note that I am aware of the posts people have made about CMake finding their Conda libraries when they don't want it to. Removing Conda from the $PATH does not work for that issue.

Comment: Maybe try to get rid of Conda. Indeed you mention having a container to hold your developpement setup so once you have your three dependencies installed normally in your Ubuntu x.y, you "freeze" it to not break it. (still, take good note of the steps you do to install all your dependencies). That said you should detail every steps that you followed in your best attempt, else it is harder to help.